# Compression of logical steps; multiple logical steps squeezed into one logical jump

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, mathematical-ability

I have read somewhere that as intelligence increases,  more and more logical steps are chunked together, so as to allow for greater logical jumps.

When doing mathematics, the different levels of "jumping" is at its most evident:

[image]

In the image above, every step of the algebraic manipulation is shown. That is, every application of a logical rule is shown.

[image]

Here, the distribution of two factors is lumped into one step. That is, the aftermath of two applications of the distributivity of factors is compressed into one step.

[image]

Finally, in this image, all steps are chunked together.

During this process, the chunked steps can be the application of different rules, unlike in my example, where the only rule applied is distributivity.

So, what is this process called? Unless my memory fails me drastically, this is definitely a scientifically evidenced process; I just can't remember the name of the process, nor the paper in which I read about it.

Comment: What is wrong with the term that you used ([chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_(psychology)))?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Well, I thought chunking only related to memory, and I'm not so sure if logical processing can be treated as so. Though, perhaps commonly-sequential syntactical rules are subject to chunking, and that the tendency of someone to chunk different syntactic sequences increases as a function of intelligence?